# Fill DataGridView from items in a list of objects, where 2 columns are supposed to be properties in a different object within the 1st one

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 user classes
Category and Product.

Category has Code and Description properties.
Product has a Code, Description, Price, Quantity and Category properties, where Category is a Category object itself.

So, I have a method that returns a List of Products, and I need to display that list in a DataGridView.

The problem is that, by using `datagridview.DataSource = listOfProducts`, the output for Category is the entire object reference, not the specific code and description properties.

So I need for those last 2 columns to basically be displayed like `listOfProducts[x].Category.Code` and `listOfProducts[x].Category.Description`

The current output is

```
Code | Description | Price | Quantity | Category
int     string       double    int      MyProject.Category
```

And I want it to be

```
Code | Description | Price | Quantity | Category Code | Category Description
int     string       double    int         int               string
```

(Additionally, if there's a way to manually rename the columns in the gridview, because as of now they would just output with the name of the properties and I'd like custom names, more user friendly)

Comment: You need to set AutoGenerateColumns flag of GridView to false. And add columns manually to the gridview and set their DataMember property and then bind gridview to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your gridview is auto generating the columns. This sample might help.

> Browsable Annotation is if you want to ignore the property to be visible on the gridview.

PRODUCT CLASS

```
public class Product
    {
        [DisplayName("Product Code")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Product Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Product Price")]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Product Qty")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [Browsable(false)]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Product Category Code")]
        public int CategoryCode
        {
            get
            {
                return Category.Code;
            }
        }

        [DisplayName("Product Category Description")]
        public string CategoryDescription
        {
            get
            {
                return Category.Description;
            }
        }
    }
```

CATEGORY CLASS

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

IMPLEMENTATION

```
var productList = new List<Product>();

        productList.Add(new Product { 
            Category = new Category { Code = 1, Description = "Category One"},
            Code = 1,
            Description = "Product One",
            Price = 100,
            Quantity = 10
        });
        productList.Add(new Product
        {
            Category = new Category { Code = 1, Description = "Category One" },
            Code = 2,
            Description = "Product Two",
            Price = 200,
            Quantity = 20
        });
        productList.Add(new Product
        {
            Category = new Category { Code = 2, Description = "Category Two" },
            Code = 3,
            Description = "Product Three",
            Price = 300,
            Quantity = 30
        });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = productList;
```

OUTPUT:

[image: OUTPUT]

I hope it helps. Happy coding.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed response. I am a bit worried as to whether this would be allowed in my project or not. Product's Category property must absolutely be a Category object. Are those CategoryCode and CategoryDescription supposed to be new properties in the Product class altogether or are they like "Split" methods for the Category property?

Comment: No worries. Good to know it helps you. CategoryCode and CategoryDescription is a new get property in the Product class if its putting it there can make this task easier because altogether the field that you want to show is there. But if its not allowed then you need to manually add those category details one by one for each row and you also need to implement renaming of the Column name for those extra field that need to manually added. Cheers!